# How to compile Python 3.4 and Excel files into .exe

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, exe, vba

I've written a Python script that drives several macros in various Excel files to format some tab-delimited data files a very specific way to be used by another program. I didn't write the Excel macros and I'd prefer not to rewrite the macros into straight Python code at this point. My customers are happy with the program so far.

I'd like the user to just be able to have the .exe available and make it easy to share, for example, without the baggage of these clunky Excel files cluttering up their directory, since that'll contain the necessary inputs.

Is it possible to create an executable from the Python script and Excel files together? If so, how would I be able to do that? I've never really had to create executables at this point but I'd be happy to do some background reading if necessary.

Comment: This might help: http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#accessing-data-files

Comment: @wnnmaw Thanks for the link. I spent most of yesterday morning getting PyInstaller to play nice with Python 3.4 on Windows. The basic commands aren't working so I'll see if I can try something different today.